# JQuery UI Datepicker | Output selected date in input date field from popup window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here's the challenge:

1) [Done] Input date field needs to be disabled with a Choose Date button that fires a modal 
2) [Done] JQuery Datepicker needs to appear in a modal when the user clicks Choose Date 
3) [Done] JQuery Datepicker needs to disable weekend and US public holiday date selection 
4) [Done] Save buttons needs to be disabled until the user selects a date using JQuery Datepicker 
5) [Not done] When the user hits the save button, the choose date modal needs to close and the selected date needs to be populated in the input date field which will still appear in the disabled mode.

---

**Here's the input form:**

## Any ideas on how to make the date value from showDate() appear in the input field?

```
<form>
  <label for="choose-date">
    <input type="text" id="choose-date" disabled onchange="showDate()">
    <button href="#" data-reveal-id="choose-date-modal">Choose Date</button>
  </label>
</form>
```

**Here's the popup the Datepicker appears in (Foundation Reveal Modal):**

```
<div id="choose-date-modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>

  <div id="datepicker-control"></div>

  <ul class="inline-list button-list">
    <li><a href="#" class="save-date-button primary button radius disabled close-reveal-modal">Save</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="secondary button radius close-reveal-modal">Cancel</a></li>
  </ul>

  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

**Here's the jQuery Datepicker that disables weekend and US public holiday date selection:**

```
/* Array of disabled public US holidays */
var disabledDays = [
    "1-1-2014",
    "1-20-2014",
    "2-17-2014",
    "2-28-2014",
    "5-26-2014",
    "7-4-2014",
    "9-1-2014",
    "10-13-2014",
    "11-11-2014",
    "11-27-2014",
    "12-25-2014"
];

/* utility function */
function nationalDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    // console.log('Checking (raw): ' + m + '-' + d + '-' + y);
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
            // console.log('bad:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y + ' / ' + disabledDays[i]);
            return [false];
        }
    }
    // console.log('good:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y);
    return [true];
}
function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker-control").datepicker({ 
    minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1), 
    maxDate: new Date(2014, 11, 31),
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
        constrainInput: true,
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
        onSelect: function showDate(date) {
            $('.save-date-button').removeClass('disabled');
            // console.log(date);
            return date;
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: in the onSelect function add $('#choose-date').val(date)